# Running/Loading a Jinja2 macro on click

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2

I have a `Jinja2` macro that currently preloads immediately on my main page although the content is hidden and only displayed after a user clicks a menu item. I want to disable preloading and only load/display the macro's content only after a user has clicked a menu item. I'm not sure if the best way to do this is via `JQuery` or if there is a `Jinja2` or `HTML` way of doing this.

Here is my menu item.

```
<li class="my_class">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="my_macro" data-target="#my_macro_id">Call My Macro</a>
</li>
```

And here is my macro.

```
{{ macros.my_macro_func(macro_id='my_macro_id' macro_content=('my_macro' | my_macro_link)) }}
```

Both of these are currently located in my `main.html` page

On the `Python`/ `Flask` side I have:

```
@app.template_filter(`my_macro_link`)
def my_macro_link_filter_func(input='some_input')
    return Markup( get_values(input) )
```

Comment: Is there a good amount of data?  If not you could preload the information but hide and unhide it with a style tag.  If there's significant data you could use jquery to request it.

Comment: @AndrewKloos I want to disable preloading, maybe I wasn't clear enough, I'll update the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well put your macro in a template by itself.  Create a GetMacro Handler in Flask with the my_macro_id as a parameter to receive your ajax request.  Have your menu item onclick point to this js script and do something like this...

```
function GetMacro(my_macro_id) {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
             if(xmlhttp.responseText != '')
             {
                 $('#ReturnedHtml').html(xmlhttp.responseText);
             }
         }
     }

     xmlhttp.open("GET","/class/GetMacro?my_macro_id=" + my_macro_id, true);
     xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So for this solution I would need to create a route for /class/GetMacro on the `Python`/`Flask` side?

Comment: Correct - with my_marco_id as a parameter so you can pass it to your render command.